# one contact form is directing to another form when "send" is clicked instead of sending

Tags: html, popup

I have a one page website and and originally I had a contact form at the end,

I then copied that contact form and changed it around a little bit and I added the form to a pop up when clicked on three separate buttons in the middle of the page.

For some reason when I fill out the form in the pop ups and press send, it scrolls down the page to the contact form at the bottom and It says "field required" in one of the fields in the bottom contact form

Here is the code for the pop up form:

```
 <footer class="panel-footer">
                                       <div class="myBtn btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default">Sign up now</div>
                                       <div class="modal">
                                       <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header">
                                            <span class="close" style="font-size:30px; color:#4A8EC8">×</span>
                                            <h2><img src="img/style="width:200px"></h2>
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="modal-body">
                                              <h4 style="color:white"><b><u>Sign up for a standard subscription</u></b></h4><br>
                            <form method="post" action="contact_standard.php" name="contactstandard" id="contactstandard">
                            <div class="results"></div>
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                                        <input name="Full Name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                        <input name="Email Address" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required>
                                    </div>

                                            </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only">Phone Number</label>
                                        <input name="Phone Number" type="number" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only">Organization Name</label>
                                        <input name="Organization Name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Organization Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                            <div align="center">
                                                <button id="submit" type="submit" style="width:40%" class="btn btncenter btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                </footer>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

here is the code for the form at the bottom of the page:

```
           <section class="section  section-contact" id="contact">
                <div class="container">
                    <header class="section-header">
                        <h2 class="section-title">Contact Us</h2>
                        <div class="section-description">Contact us at any time - we love to talk.</div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="section-content">
                        <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                            <div class="results"></div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only">Message</label>
                                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" style="height: 181px" rows="6" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required>
                                    </div><br>

                                            </div><br>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add closing `</form>` tags on both the popup and bottom contact sections

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
...your form
</form>
```